# Windows 10 GPO causing restrictions within Windows 10 UI

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I'm working on an issue here at our location that is causing some massive headaches. I've opened a few tickets with MS primer level support with no results. They are still "Investigating" the issue. It's been since December.

We are running windows 10 Enterprise with GPOs associated on the machines. Our GPO is currently causing an issue where you're unable to forget any saved wifi networks (Personal and not GPO assigned wifi networks) Wifi selections (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll5My.jpg)

When using the Windows 10 Settings menu and Wifi sub-section, the forget option on the actually network is active. Once clicked, it becomes greyed out and the network remains there (see pic above). Additionally, when attempting to add the network with the "Add a new network" button, nothing allows you to save. The error when trying to save the network is "Couldn't add the new network."

Unable to add new network (https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4upD.jpg)

A workaround to add the network would be visit control panel -> Network and sharing center -> Setup a new connection or network. If you visit and add it manually here it all works fine. I'm able to save those networks and forget them with no issues under the Control Panel UI but unable to do so under the Windows 10 Settings wifi UI. Manually Add Network (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQeTg.jpg)

The main problem is we cannot ask clients to visit this location to add or remove networks but instead want to use the Windows 10 wifi setting UI enter image description here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vixh.jpg)

We literally deleted the registry key containing the SSID and the XML file but the SSID still shows under Known networks and doesn't allow us to forget it.

We know that GPO is causing the restriction but really curious on what could cause it as it's only a restriction on the Windows 10 Settings UI. I've also uploaded the gpresult of the GPO's applied to my account. (https://ufile.io/gqx06)

Comment: Have you tried disabling each group policy systematically until you find the conflict?

Comment: That's the current step we are on. We have hundreds that we would have to filter out.

Comment: Your search for the GPO may be speed by a binary search (Add/Remove half of the GPOs, find the half with the issue, split that half and repeat)

Comment: 100's of GPO's? That's not a good design. I'm not knocking you, I'm just saying. Are there actually hundreds of GPO's that apply to this machine?

Comment: Yup. Check the .html file attached. Currently doing a binary search to see what's causing this.